# kubernetes clean way to define environment variables for multiple environments

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm working with a web app and there are multiple environments that we deploy this to; prod, staging, multiple QA environments, and even some developer environments when necessary. We're migrating to kubernetes from elastic beanstalk and trying to set up the config/yaml files in as clean a way as we can. The issue is, we've defined a yaml file for each environment that has some secrets in it, and this is getting a little bit hard to maintain with lots of copy/paste. Below is an example of the files/contents:

**disclaimer** - this work was mostly done by the devops team and I'm a web engineer trying to assist them, so I will try to answer any questions as best as I can, but I may not have all the right answers

folder structure:

```
- k8s // root folder
 - deployment.yaml
 - production
   - production-params.yaml
 - staging
   - staging-1-params.yaml
   - staging-2-params.yaml
   - qa-1-params.yaml
 - developers
   - some-dev-params.yaml
```

The contents of each one of these `*-params.yaml` files is almost identical, let's look at a couple examples.

production-params.yaml

```
apiVersion: 'kubernetes-client.io/v1'
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: prod-params
spec:
  backendType: systemManager
  data:
    - key:  /xxx/production/ENV_VAR_1
      name: ENV_VAR_1
    - key:  /xxx/production/ENV_VAR_2
      name: ENV_VAR_2
    - key:  /xxx/production/ENV_VAR_3
      name: ENV_VAR_3
    - key:  /xxx/production/ENV_VAR_4
      name: ENV_VAR_4
```

staging-1-params.yaml

```
apiVersion: 'kubernetes-client.io/v1'
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: prod-params
spec:
  backendType: systemManager
  data:
    - key:  /xxx/staging1/ENV_VAR_1
      name: ENV_VAR_1
    - key:  /xxx/staging1/ENV_VAR_2
      name: ENV_VAR_2
    - key:  /xxx/staging1/ENV_VAR_3
      name: ENV_VAR_3
    - key:  /xxx/staging1/ENV_VAR_4
      name: ENV_VAR_4
```

and every other params file is like this, with only the file paths in the 'key' changing, but its almost identical. Is there a way we can make these somewhat dynamic or cleaner? I'm not a devops/k8s pro and did some research, seems like Helm can be helpful here but not sure how to use it to solve this problem. I read a tutorial that was a little helpful but I'm still confused. If anyone knows of any resources or has solved this problem in the past, I'd really appreciate the help

Comment: Take a look at this article about using Kustomize to manage different configurations: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-your-kubernetes-configurations-with-kustomize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of replacement Helm is good at.  If you write a Helm chart, you can use its templating syntax to fill in a specific part of the YAML:

```yaml
# templates/external-secret.yaml
apiVersion: 'kubernetes-client.io/v1'
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: prod-params
spec:
  backendType: systemManager
  data:
    - key:  /xxx/{{ .Values.environment }}/ENV_VAR_1
      name: ENV_VAR_1
    - key:  /xxx/{{ .Values.environment }}/ENV_VAR_2
      name: ENV_VAR_2
{{/* etc. */}}
```

You can then provide a YAML file of settings per environment:

```yaml
# production.yaml
environment: production
```

```yaml
# staging-1.yaml
environment: staging-1
```

When you go to deploy the application, you can provide one of these files as a command-line option, and the contents of the file will be visible to the templating engine as `.Values`.

```sh
helm install the-app . -f staging-1.yaml
```

That approach would let you put all of the things that are "the same" in the `templates` directory, and all of the things that are different per environment in the per-environment YAML values files.